# Why sometimes tensorflow runs slower and slower with the process of training?

Tags: tensorflow

I train a RNN network, the first epoch used 7.5 hours. But with the training process runs, tensorflow runs slower and slower, the second epoch used 55 hours. I checked the code, most APIs that become slower with time are these :

1. `session.run([var1, var1, ...], feed_dict=feed)`,
2. `tensor.eval(feed_dict=feed)`.

For example, one line code is `session.run[var1, var2, ...], feed_dict=feed)`, as the program begins, It uses 0.1 seconds, but with the process runs, the time used for this line of code becomes bigger and bigger, After 10 hours, time this line spends comes to 10 seconds.

I have been befall this several times. Which triggered this? How could I do to avoid this?

If this line of code: `self.shapes = [numpy.zeros(g[1].get_shape(), numy.float32) for g in self.compute_gradients]`  adds nodes to the graph of tensorflow? I suspect this maybe the reason. This line of code will be called many times periodically，and `self` is not an object of `tf.train.optimizer`.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a memory leak. Try following the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/3883/how-to-debug-a-memory-leak-in-tensorflow/13426/use-graph-finalize-to-catch-nodes-being-added-to-the-graph#t=20160822041413026848) to track down the cause. The `[numpy.zeros(...) for g in self.compute_gradients]` line might add nodes to the graph, if `self` is a `tf.train.Optimizer` object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try finalizing your graph after you create it (graph.finalize()). This will prevent operations to be added to the graph. I also think self.compute_gradients is adding operations to the graph. Try defining the operation outside your loop and running it inside your loop

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried `graph.finalize()`, and there should be no memory leak at all. And I also deleted the code of frequently allocating large memory like `numpy.ndarray` . I will run several epochs to check it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. My solution was putting

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

after each epoch or sample.  This resets the graph and frees up all the resources used in a way closing the session does not.

Comment: I got this error: `AssertionError: Do not use tf.reset_default_graph() to clear nested graphs. If you need a cleared graph, exit the nesting and create a new graph.`